# Getting my location LatLng from Mapbox in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I'm trying to get my location using `mapbox` on an android application built with kotlin. I'm using the `locationComponent` method to get it, here is my code :

```
class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {
    private var permissionsManager: PermissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)
    private var mapboxMap: MapboxMap? = null
    private var myCurrentLocation: LatLng? = null
    var navigationMapRoute: NavigationMapRoute? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }
        val theActivity = activity as NavigationActivity?
        theSteps = theActivity?.theSteps
        case = theActivity?.case
        case = theActivity.case
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        activity?.let {
            Mapbox.getInstance(
                it,
                getString(com.innoventiq.arkbeh.R.string.mapbox_access_token2)
            )
        }
        val root =
            inflater.inflate(com.innoventiq.arkbeh.R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)
        getMyLocation()
    }

    override fun onExplanationNeeded(permissionsToExplain: MutableList<String>?) {
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            com.innoventiq.arkbeh.R.string.user_location_permission_explanation,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        )
            .show()
    }

    override fun onPermissionResult(granted: Boolean) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap?.style!!)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                com.innoventiq.arkbeh.R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            )
                .show()
        }
    }
    override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap

        mapboxMap.cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(myCurrentLocation)
            .zoom(14.0)
            .build()
        //mapView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.OUTDOORS) {
            enableLocationComponent(it)

        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun enableLocationComponent(loadedMapStyle: Style) {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(activity)) {


            // Create and customize the LocationComponent's options
            val customLocationComponentOptions = activity?.let {
                LocationComponentOptions.builder(it)
                    .trackingGesturesManagement(true)
                    .accuracyColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            activity!!,
                            com.innoventiq.arkbeh.R.color.colorGreen
                        )
                    )
                    .build()

            }

            val locationComponentActivationOptions =
                activity?.let {
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(it, loadedMapStyle)
                        .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
                        .build()
                }


            // Get an instance of the LocationComponent and then adjust its settings
            mapboxMap?.locationComponent?.apply {

                // Activate the LocationComponent with options
                locationComponentActivationOptions?.let {
                    this?.activateLocationComponent(
                        it
                    )
                }

                // Enable to make the LocationComponent visible
                isLocationComponentEnabled = true


                // Set the LocationComponent's camera mode
                cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING

                // Set the LocationComponent's render mode
                renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS

            }
        } else {
            permissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(activity)
        }


    }

    private fun getMyLocation() {
        myCurrentLocation =
            mapboxMap?.locationComponent?.lastKnownLocation?.latitude?.let {
                mapboxMap!!.locationComponent.lastKnownLocation?.longitude?.let { it1 ->
                    LatLng(it,
                        it1
                    )
                }
            }
        println("the location : $myCurrentLocation ")
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView.onLowMemory()
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): PlaceholderFragment {
            return PlaceholderFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used almost the full fragment code just trying to give you a clear view of the steps I've used to get the location.  When it comes to the line `println("the location : $myCurrentLocation ")` 
inside the `getMyLocation()` function , it returns this output `the location : null` ,, any help on this ?

**Note**

When the map loads, it shows my location perfectly and tracks it, but I just can't get the `LatLng` of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, used `LocationComponent.LocationEngine.getLastLocation` callBack to get it , here is the code:

```
    private fun getMyLocation() {
        mapboxMap?.locationComponent?.locationEngine?.getLastLocation(object :
            LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LocationEngineResult?) {
                if (result != null) {
                    myCurrentLocation =
                        LatLng(result.locations[0].latitude, result.locations[0].longitude)
                    println("my location is : $myCurrentLocation")
                    getTheRoute(myCurrentLocation)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
                toast(getString(R.string.failed_get_location))
            }

        })
    }
```